# Validation of c# winform controls that are bounded to an object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I created winform controls in my app using the toolbox. I also set default value, min and max of those controls in the settings page. Then, I bounded those controls in an object. Something that looks like this:

```
 private void InitializeBinding()
    {
        enable_checkbox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", ObjectConfig, "enable");
        area_numeric.DataBindings.Add("Value", ObjectConfig, "area");

    }
```

and my ObjectConfig class have this:

```
class ObjectConfig {
   private bool bEnable;
   private int iArea;

   public bool enable
   {
     get { return bEnable; }
     set { bEnable = value; }
   }

   public int area
   {
     get { return iArea; }
     set { iArea = value; }
   }
}
```

The binding is working great. No problems whatsoever. Then, I am converting this object to xml and I am saving it to a config xml file.The problem is that if someone edited the value of area in the xml file to a number that goes beyond the set min and max value and the xml is loaded and converted to an object, there is an error since the object is binded to a control with min and max value. Is there a good way to provide validation in this type of approach?

Comment: are the min and max values hard coded? or where do you get them?

Comment: min and max values were set under the settings of the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constraint it in the setter of the property and check there whether it is within the limits. You can put the limit values into project properties variables like this (sorry for the German version [Dictionary](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/)):

[image]

And in the setter you can check these ranges and acces the variables like the following:

```
public class ObjectConfig
{
    private bool bEnable;
    private int iArea;

    public bool enable
    {
        get { return bEnable; }
        set { bEnable = value; }
    }

    public int area
    {
        get { return iArea; }
        set
        {
            if (value < Properties.Settings.Default.AreaMin)
            {
                iArea = Properties.Settings.Default.AreaMin;
            }
            else if (value > Properties.Settings.Default.AreaMax)
            {
                iArea = Properties.Settings.Default.AreaMax;
            }
            else
            {
                iArea = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way your values will always within the set range irrespective of what the user edits in the *.XML file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is surely possible. However, in the future, there is a possibility that the attributes of ObjectConfig would reach to about more than 10. As much as possible, I do not want to hard code all the 10 min and max values of each attribute. Are there no other ways?

Comment: @Redis1001 I did not really focus on how the min and max values are implemented. I answered your request for a validation approach. This is how you can avoid that not allowed values are assigned to the property. The managing of your min and max values is up to you. :)

Comment: @Redis1001 If the min and max values are set "under the settings of the controls" why don't you just use those values?

Comment: I really do want to use the min and max values that were set on the settings but I have to use it inside the setter since I am converting the data directly from XML to object using XMLSerializer.

Comment: @Redis1001 I edited my answer. Now you can save your limit values in the properties settings and use the variables in the setter. Have a look

Comment: Hi.. thank you! May I please know how to access the project properties variables? Thank you.

Comment: @Redis1001 As I wrote in the code. `Properties.Settings.Default.YourVariableName`. You have to set the variables in the Project where your class `ObjectConfig` is